# uibezier path - will not display

Tags: ios, ios4, uibezierpath

I am trying to use UIbezierPaths for the first time and I am having no success in displaying it in the view. I am using a very old version of xcode (3.2.6).

```
-(void)drawshape:(CGRect)Rect {

  UIBezierPath *cloudpath = [UIBezierPath bezierPath];

  [cloudpath moveToPoint:CGPointMake(100.0, 100.0)]; 
  [cloudpath addLineToPoint:CGPointMake(200, 200)];
  [cloudpath addLineToPoint:CGPointMake(200, 300)];
  [cloudpath addLineToPoint:CGPointMake(250, 330)];
  [cloudpath addLineToPoint:CGPointMake(20, 400)];
  [cloudpath closePath];

  cloudpath.lineWidth = 2;
  [[UIColor blueColor]setStroke];

  [cloudpath stroke];

}
```

I have also Imported QuartzCore. I have only added -(void)drawshape in viewcontroller.h

When I build, i have no errors.Any help is massively welcomed

Comment: When are you calling `drawshape:`? If it's in your view controller instead of your view things will be more complex - do you have a `UIView` subclass?

Comment: I have a view, the original one that was set up when i started my project. I am really new to this.

Comment: drawshape was added as i wasn't too sure where to run the code. school boy error?

Comment: Why is this tagged as `ios4`? You're not actually developing for iOS 4 are you?

Answer (score 2):

You will need to initiate the drawing from overriding drawRect: in a custom UIView and not in your view controller.